# How to respond to touch action on status bar?

Tags: react-native

[StatusBarIOS](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/StatusBar/StatusBarIOS.ios.js) doesn't seem to have a touch hook so how would one listed one? Use case would be tap to status bar to scroll to top.

Comment: You can have look at the **ScrollView** module. It has a property `scrollsToTop` which scrolls the view to the top when the status bar is tapped

Comment: @NishanthShankar Thanks, totally missed that one!

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: there's no such way but ScrollView takes `scrollsToTop` property which allows this to happen automatically.